# Unity3D Debugging in runtime on Kindle Fire HD

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, kindle-fire

Like in subject, Can I debug in runtime scripts in Unity3D on Kindle Fire HD? anyone done this before ? In MonoDev "attach to Process I can see only Editor.

Comment: Are you asking about android remote debugging, or Unity for android debugging?

Comment: "Can I debug in runtime scripts in Unity3D" - Unity for Android.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Debug.Log();` function to debug. If you need to Debug while running on the Kindle You will have to create GUI Script to render text onto the screen.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnGUI() {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

For more details refer this Unity Docs page -https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html